# Xero API - Authenticate using just cURL

Tags: xero-api

Is it possible to just use cURL to handle the authentication with the Xero API for a private application? I've played with the PHP library and that all works well but I'd like to just use straight cURL commands for the HTTP Requests which it can obviously do, just not sure if I can use cURL to handle the OAuth 1.0a authentication?

Comment: Xero API can be accessed for Private Apps with 2-legged OAuth authentication, which means that yes you can perform it with cURL because it only involves HTTP requests between the client and the server.

But you are going to need to build the requests yourself, with the right header and body. This is heavy.

This might help: https://gist.github.com/john2x/3871758

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to use Filemaker Pro you can do this easily via the BaseElements plugin from Goya using `BE_Xero_SetTokens`, and then including the consumer key and your private key as the username and password in subsequent HTTP requests.

Details [here](https://baseelementsplugin.zendesk.com/).